# FullCalendar - hide certain hours in day view

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery FullCalendar plugin and want to hide certain hours in day view.

I want to show the calendar from 6am to 10am and from 12pm to 4pm.

I already set `minTime: '6:00'` and `maxTime: '14:00'` but I also need to hide the hours between 10am to 12pm too.

Comment: Are you using a jQuery widget, or an HTML5 input date?

Comment: Not, I'm using Full Calendar Jquery Plugin http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Have you tried using two calendars, each with different `minTime` and `maxTime`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, fullcalendar relies on Moment.js durations. As far as I can tell, you can't have a duration that is multiple durations.

However, it seems that fullcalendar renders the agenda first, then calculates the position of where the events need to be after the agenda is laid out. So, if a CSS solution is acceptable, you could always do the following:

```
[data-time^="10"]>td, [data-time^="11"]>td, [data-time^="12"]>td
{
    height: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

This works by matching the table row's "data-time" attribute. The match pattern is a prefix match, to save some typing. If you don't want to use `^=` to match the prefix, you can try these:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Edit to demonstrate (works on Chrome 52). As you can see, I also needed to make the children of the affected cells hidden (`display: none;`). Also note that you'll need to filter your own data to exclude or alter dates times that fall in that range. I've included some events that show what happens if you don't take this precaution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
   left: 'prev,next today',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'agendaDay'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaDay',
  defaultDate: '2016-06-12',
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true,
  events: [
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-06-12T10:30:00',
    end: '2016-06-12T12:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Loooong Meeting',
    start: '2016-06-12T09:30:00',
    end: '2016-06-12T14:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Lunch',
    start: '2016-06-12T12:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-06-12T14:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Happy Hour',
    start: '2016-06-12T17:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Dinner',
    start: '2016-06-12T20:00:00'
   }
  ]
 });
})
```

```css
[data-time^="10"]>td,
[data-time^="11"]>td,
[data-time^="12"]>td
{
  height: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}

[data-time^="10"]>td *,
[data-time^="11"]>td *,
[data-time^="12"]>td *
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I check, but this pugin not works with this attribute; but it was a example, the hours that I need hide can change agree client diary.

Comment: @Jochi Added a working example. Pay attention to your event data.